# Sencha Touch 2: Cannot disable the disableCache mechanism - app does not run offline

Tags: caching, extjs, sencha-touch-2, offline, disable-caching

In my SenchaTouch 2 app the first lines in app.js read:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig( {enabled: true, disableCaching: false} );
Ext.data.Connection.disableCaching = false;
Ext.data.JsonP.disableCaching = false;
Ext.data.proxy.Server.prototype.noCache = false;
Ext.Ajax.disableCaching = false;
```

The app compiles to the production version without errors or warnings. It loads and runs from the server. When I try to run it offline in Chrome, those 404 errors occur

```
GET http://myServer/m/Override/...=1346682646496 /m/Override/slider/Slider.js?_dc=1346682646496:1
GET http://myServer/m/app.json?1346682646693 /m/:6
```

which indicate that the timestamp of the disableCache parameter is appended to the GET requests. Therefore the application does not load offline. It hangs at the "Application is being loaded..." screen. How can I enable caching and avoid this _dc parameter?

The SDK version is 2.0.1.1

-- update: Found workaround. Integrated Slider.js in app.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug or rather the feature was not implemented properly. It didnt work for me in sencha 2.1 either.